# Is it sufficient to convert ', < and > to avoid XSS in JavaScript strings?

Tags: xss, javascript, html

Is it sufficient to convert `'` to `&#039;` , `>` to `&gt;` and `<`  to `&lt;` to avoid XSS when inserting untrusted data into a JavaScript string as below?

```
<script>
param='payload';
</script>
```

Are there any examples of situations where the above conversion is not sufficient to avoid XSS?

Comment: Why would filtering a single character fix XSS?  What about `param='</script><script>alert(1)//'`

Comment: Or, if more than one field is filled out, a simple backslash in the first and `;alert(1)//` in the second.

Answer (score 9):

Don't rely on using your own "conversion" rules, [OWASP recommends](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) using a security-focused encoding library to make sure the necessary rules are properly implemented:

> Escape the following characters with HTML entity encoding to prevent switching into any execution context, such as script, style, or event handlers. In addition to the 5 characters significant in XML (&, <, >, ", '), the forward slash is included as it helps to end an HTML entity.
>
> HTML entity encoding is okay for untrusted data that you put in the body of the HTML document, such as inside a `<div>` tag. However, it would not be sufficient in a number of cases, such as "nested contexts":
>
> ```
> <script>...param used directly here...</script>
> <!--...param used inside an HTML comment...-->
> <div ...param used in an attribute name=test />
> <param as a tag name href="/test" />
> <style>...param used directly in CSS...</style>
> ```
>
> In general, never use ***param*** inside any of these nested entities, even if HTML entity encoded.

Comment: i agree that we should use security focused libary but i was looking for a specific example for the mentioned context. any ideas??

Comment: @Milen Your posts need to contain citation.  Link to the OWASP XSS filter evasion cheat sheet,  or XSS prevention cheat sheet.

Answer (score 8):

It isn’t sufficient, no. Contrived backslash example:

```
<script>
var param1 = '{{ param1 }}'; var param2 = '{{ param2 }}';
</script>
```

```
param1=\&param2=;alert(1)//
```

```
<script>
var param1 = '\'; var param2 = ';alert(1)//';
</script>
```

Not to mention that your data won’t survive intact:

```
<script>
var param1 = '&lt;';
alert(param1); // Shows up as &lt;, not <
</script>
```

Newlines (`\r`, `\n`, `\u2028`, `\u2029`) can also break a JavaScript string, though it’s probably rare for that to create a vulnerability, since it’s invariably a syntax error. If you absolutely need to put user input in a variable in an inline `<script>` inline, I would recommend JSON-encoding followed by a replacement of `</` with `<\/` and `<!` with `<\!`. The best way, though, is to encode outside of the script, either with reliable HTML encoding in an attribute:

```
<div id="my-information" data-something="{{ param1 }}"></div>

<script>
var param1 = document.getElementById('my-information').getAttribute('data-something');
</script>
```

or in a non-executable script element, good for text (like JSON) that would need lots of escaping in an attribute:

```
<script id="my-information" type="application/json">
<%- JSON.stringify(param1).replace(/</g, "\\u003c") %>
</script>

<script>
var param1 = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('my-information').textContent);
</script>
```

Not having dynamic scripts lets you implement strong CSPs.